# Error installing PyBluez - use_2to3 is invalid

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pybluez

I tried so many times with pip install pybluez, idk how to resolve it, heres the error:

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pybluez
Using cached PyBluez-0.23.tar.gz (97 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [1 lines of output]
error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried solving this error with pip install wheel, pip install setuptools==68, but it dosent function